# How to return some predefined value when no row returned from big query with multiple column is selected

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

My query has multiple column being selected but now i want when no returned I want some dummy value to be returned.

For example in the following query:

```sql
SELECT a.abc, b.def, c.ghi
FROM comp a, damp b, champ c, omp d 
WHERE a.id=b.id
      and b.id=c.id
      and c.id= d.id
ORDER BY a.abc desc
```

if there is no row returned I wanted to display atleast one column with some value, can somebody suggest me how can I achieve this.
I have already gone through some suggestion but none worked. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please tag your question with just 1 DBMS - is it MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: Please be more specific: "no row returned" after executing this SELECT, or no rows found in the joining tables?

Comment: Let your *application logik* work a bit. I.e. exceute query check if you get rows and if not run a query agains `dual` returning the `no rows`. You'll get *far better performance* as if you delegate this to the database query with `not exists`. Solving this problem in `SQL` is possible, but I'll consider it as *anti-pattern*.

Answer (score 3):

In oracle you could do something like this:

```
WITH mybigselect AS
(
SELECT a.abc, b.def, c.ghi
FROM comp a
     JOIN damp b ON a.id = b.id
     JOIN champ c ON b.id = c.id
     JOIN omp d ON c.id = d.id 
ORDER BY a.abc desc  
)
SELECT * FROM mybigselect
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Nothing found', NULL, NULL FROM mybigselect
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM mybigselect)
```

Note 1:  that both rows in the `UNION ALL` needs to return columns of the same datatype. You can't return a number in the first column of `SELECT * FROM mybigselect`  and "nothing found" in the query after `UNION ALL`

Note 2: rewrote the query using ANSI-JOIN style syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend:

```
WITH cte as (
      SELECT a.abc, b.def, c.ghi
      FROM comp do JOIN
           damp d
           ON d.id = co.id JOIN
           champ c
           ON ch.id = d.id
           omp o
           ON o.id = ch.id
     )
SELECT *
FROM cte
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Some value', NULL, NLL
FROM dual
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM cte)
ORDER BY abc DESC;
```

Notes:

- The value has to be compatible with the type of the column.  So, if `abc` is not a string, then `'Some value'` is not appropriate.  You haven't provided enough information to determine what value should be in which column.
- The `ORDER BY` should be in the outermost query, not the CTE.
- *Never* use comas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.
- This version uses *meaningful* table aliases (table name abbreviations) rather than arbitrary letters.